# Site caching file, need this to stop

Tags: php, apache, caching

I have a script that generates a new CSV file (in my web directory) every half hour, it replaces the original one and puts a new one in its place with the same file name, the file is linked to on my website.

When I download the file from my website, instead of getting an updated version I get a file that is the same as the first time I downloaded it on this computer.

My first thought was to make sure that the script is still running properly and after testing, I can confirm that it is.

I then cleared the cache and download history in Chrome and tried to download it again, this time it worked as intended.

I am running this off of a rackspace cloud server running ubuntu and apache.  I assume there is some setting that I need to reconfigure to fix this problem.  Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A somewhat dirty solution is to append to the script that let you download the file a random number (or maybe the timestamp) as parameter to prevent the caching.

For example:

> www.example.com/download.php?file=my.csv&rand=123456789

Comment: FYI exact same trick one uses when debugging Silverlight applications (browser caches the Silverlight executables).

Comment: I currently link to the file directly so like : www.example.com/my.csv Can I make this work still?

Comment: Here is what I tried and it is not working, what did I do wrong?     echo "<a href=\"Summary.csv&time=" . time() . "\">Download CSV Version</a> &nbsp;";

Comment: @jimstandard You have to write echo "<a href=\"Summary.csv?time=" . time() . "\">Download CSV Version</a> Note the ? instead of the &.

Answer (score 1):

The second example on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) shows how to disable caching on many clients and proxies. You should use something like this.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

With this solution, you can cache the page where your link resides. The link will work anyway.